# product $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let, for $j=1,2, X_{j}$ be a nonempty set, $\mathcal{E}_{j} \subset \mathcal{P}\left(X_{j}\right)$ be a nonempty collection of subsets of $X_{j}$ and
$\mathcal{M}_{j}=\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E}_{j})$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{E}_{j}$. Set $\mathcal{E}=\left\{A \times X_{2} | A \in \mathcal{E}_{1}\right\} \cup\left\{X_{1} \times B | B \in \mathcal{E}_{2}\right\}$. 
Prove that $\mathcal{M}_{1} \otimes \mathcal{M}_{2}=\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$.

I have proved that $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E}) \subset\mathcal{M}_{1} \otimes \mathcal{M}_{2}$. But I cannot prove the inverse direction. I tried to prove that $\mathcal{R}=\left\{ \cup_1^nA_i\times B_i|A_i\in\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E_1}),B_i\in\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E_2}),\forall n\right\}\subset\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$, but I failed. Any hint will be appreicated! Thank you!

Definition: $\mathcal{M}_{1} \otimes \mathcal{M}_{2}=\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{R})$.

Comment: How is $\mathcal{M}_1 \otimes \mathcal{M}_2$ defined in your course?

Comment: @DanielFischer Hi, I have made some modifications. Please see the new version. Thank you!

Comment: Okay. Split it into smaller steps. Can you show $A\times B \in \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$ for $A \in \mathcal{M}_1$ and $B \in \mathcal{M}_2$?

Comment: Actually, that's exactly where I was stuck. Because $\mathcal{E_j}$ is not even an algebra.

Comment: Then try to make two steps of that. Look at $A \times X_2$ first.

Comment: Yeah, I know the idea. $\left\{A\times X_2|A\in \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E_1})\right\} = \mathcal{M}(\left\{A\times X_2|A\in \mathcal{E_1}\right\})$ is pretty obvious. But I wonder how to show this explicitly and rigorously?

Comment: Consider $\mathcal{A} = \{ A \subset X_1 : A\times X_2 \in \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})\}$. It's obvious that $\mathcal{E}_1 \subset \mathcal{A}$. Next you show that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. That's just routine verification of the definitions. It follows that $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E}_1) \subset \mathcal{A}$, thus $\{ A \times X_2 : A \in \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E}_1)\} \subset \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$. The same works for $X_1 \times B$ of course. Then $A \times B = (A\times X_2) \cap (X_1 \times B)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have known this strategy! Thanks again!